# Google Measurement Protocol not registering custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, roku, measurement-protocol

I'm using the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) to register events with HTTP requests.  I'm building this for a Roku app I'm working on.  The events are getting sent and registered, but it seems the [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#customs) aren't working.

Here's what I'm sending

```
Destination URL:
    https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect

POST body:
    v=1                             // version
    &dh=www.my-site.com             // document hostname
    &tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X              // Tracking ID / Property ID
    &uid=(a user id)                // user id
    &cid=(an assigned UUID)         // Anonymous Client ID
    &sr=1280x720                    // screen resolution of the tv

    &t=event                        // Event hit type
    &ec=ExampleCategory             // Event Category. Required
    &ea=ExampleAction               // Event Action. Required
    &el=ExampleLabel                // Event label

    &cd1=WAAA                       // Custom dimension 1, Station
    &cd2=(some id)                  // Custom dimension 2, User ID

    &z=1432199801                   // Cache buster
```

When I go to `Behavior > Events > Top Events` in Google Analytics and set the secondary dimension as being Station for instance, none of the events show up.  The events show up when I take off the secondary dimension though, so it seems like Google Analytics just isn't liking something about the custom definitions.

- I've tried waiting 24 hours to see if there's a time delay problem, but that didn't help.
- I've also made sure to turn on the custom definitions and set them to "Hit" scope type from the Admin panel in Analytics as well.

When I submit the above to https://ssl.google-analytics.com/debug/collect (the validation server that returns errors if there's something wrong with the request), it says the request is valid.

Any idea what could be going on here?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you set up the custom dimensions in the GA property?

Comment: I'm not too sure which GA property you mean.  If you're referring to setting up the custom dimensions from the admin panel in GA, then yes, I have.

Comment: That was what I meant. Sorry, I can see that you mentioned that in your question as well.

Comment: Did you check the hit in the dev console to see if the query parameters include your custom dimensions?

Comment: Unfortunately since I'm sending out the requests from a Roku device, I don't really know how I can check the dev console in my browser.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm not able to send to events from Roku either...